# How to add multiple form values using vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**select_room.blade.php**

```
<input type="hidden" name="rooms[]" :value="selected">
```

**app.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#panel',
    data: {
        selected: []
    },
    methods: {
        selectRoom(room) {
            if (!this.selected.find(room => room)) {
                this.selected.push(room);
            } else {
                this.selected.pop(room);
            }

            console.log(this.selected);
        }
    }
});
```

[image: rooms]

When I click on room buttons (eg: 105,106) room numbers will be added to `selected` array. But when
I check my $request->rooms its showing `null`. I just wanted to how to add multiple values to `name=rooms[]` using vue.js
Thanks in advance!

[image: error]

Comment: What about `<input type="hidden" name="rooms[]" v-model="selected">` ?

Comment: Tried, Not working mate :)

Comment: When I select one room it's working, for multiple selections its showing `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't setup a PHP/Blade/Vue.js environment but the following seems to be achieving what you're looking for. I got a `rooms` GET variable with coma separated selected values.

```
<div id="app">
    <form method="GET">
        <button @click.prevent="selectRoom(1)">1</button>
        <button @click.prevent="selectRoom(2)">2</button>
        <button @click.prevent="selectRoom(3)">3</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="rooms" :value="selected" />
        <input type="submit" text="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            selected: [],
        },
        methods: {
            selectRoom(room) {
                if (!this.selected.includes(room)) {
                    this.selected.push(room);
                } else {
                   this.selected.pop(room);
                }
                console.log(Object.values(this.selected));
            }
        },
    }
)
</script>
```